# Конкурентная загрузка файлов через http.Client, golang

Tags: golang, concurrency

Прошу помочь разобраться с такой проблемой. Пробую получать файлы Get-запросом в нескольких  горутинах:

```
type RemoteImages []RemoteImage
type RemoteImage struct {
     Lang    string `json:"lang"`
     Name    string `json:"name"`
     URL     string `json:"url"`
     Payload []byte `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    images := RemoteImages {
         RemoteImage {
            Lang: "ru",
            Name: "name"
            URL : "https://.....",
         },
         /* еще несколько элементов RemoteImage */
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    for i, _ := range images {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(imageIn *RemoteImage, wg *sync.WaitGroup){

           defer wg.Done()
           resp, _ := client.Get(imageIn.URL)
           imageIn.Payload, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
           defer resp.Body.Close()

           }(&images[i], wg)
       }

       wg.Wait()
}
```

По итогам бенчмарков такой подход  работает дольше, чем если бы я получал картинки синхронно. Если заменить работу внутри горутины на time.Sleep(time.Seconds*n), то функция отрабатывает как запланированно, но именно с получением данных по http все неоднозначно.Как можно оптимизировать/изменить код что бы получить данные конкуретно? Зарнее спасибо за ответы)
P.S
Пробовал передавать RemoteImage через канал, но, похоже, оверхед на работу с каналами еще больше. если слайс небольшой.

Comment: А что за бенчмарки? Может сервер который раздает файлы не асинхронный и работает в один поток? И waitgroup не надо в качестве параметра в горутину передавать.

Comment: @rusnasonov, да, я думал про это. Замерял и через  go test -bench . -benchmem и просто при помощи time.Now() и time.Since() время работы. Картинки для тестов брал с разных серверов, как для синхронного подхода так и для конкурентого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ сервера нужно через канал передавать, а не обращаться к объекту основной горутины

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type RemoteImages []RemoteImage
type RemoteImage struct {
    Lang    string `json:"lang"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    URL     string `json:"url"`
    Payload []byte `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
    images := RemoteImages{
        RemoteImage{
            Lang: "ru",
            Name: "img1",
            URL:  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beach-exotic-holiday-248797.jpg&fm=jpg",
        },
        RemoteImage{
            Lang: "ru",
            Name: "img2",
            URL:  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beauty-bloom-blue-67636.jpg&fm=jpg",
        },
        RemoteImage{
            Lang: "ru",
            Name: "img3",
            URL:  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=beautiful-beauty-blue-414612.jpg&fm=jpg",
        },
        RemoteImage{
            Lang: "ru",
            Name: "img4",
            URL:  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1308881/pexels-photo-1308881.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=ao-dai-beautiful-beauty-1308881.jpg&fm=jpg",
        },
    }

    client := &http.Client{}

    resultChan := make(chan *RemoteImage)

    for _, image := range images {
        go func(imageIn RemoteImage, outChan chan<- *RemoteImage) {
            t := time.Now()
            resp, err := client.Get(imageIn.URL)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Print(err)
            }
            payload, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            resp.Body.Close()
            outChan <- &RemoteImage{
                Lang:    imageIn.Lang,
                Name:    imageIn.Name,
                URL:     imageIn.URL,
                Payload: payload,
            }
            fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
        }(image, resultChan)
    }

    t := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < len(images); i++ {
        payload := <-resultChan
        fmt.Printf(`Got result %d: %s, %d`, i+1, payload.Name, len(payload.Payload))
        fmt.Println("")
    }
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t))
}
```